# Safari not updating my useState boolean value

Tags: reactjs, safari, react-router, react-hooks, use-state

My auth context works by Saving loggedIn state which has a value of true or false to localStorage

It works fine on all browsers But recently it stopped working on safari and the state just shows null as value

What could be causing that? Also some components pages I generate using useParams from react-router-dom ends up showing 404 error on safari but works well on chrome

auth context code below:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

const AuthProvider = (props) => {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [loggedIn, setLoggedin] = useState(false);
const token = localStorage.getItem("userToken");

useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('logged-in');
    setLoggedin(JSON.parse(data));
    setLoading(false);
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('logged-in', loggedIn)
  },[loggedIn])

  const login = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoggedin(true);
    }, 500);
  };

const logout = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoggedin(false);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const authContextValue = { login, loggedIn, logout, loading };
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={authContextValue} {...props} />;
};

const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };
```

Comment: When you log in, are you able to see "true" in your local storage in Safari?

Comment: it just shows null
it doesn't update it to true
but other browsers updates it to true

Comment: Is the login() function getting called? And reaching the setLoggedin ?

Comment: Yes it gets called once login is successful
And it works fine on other browsers. The state gets updated. But on Safari on Mac, it doesn't update the state. But it does on chrome on macOs but Safari and chrome on ios, it doesn't work

Comment: Try wrapping your local storage code in a try catch to see if there is any exception. There could be some error which you are not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was from safari not adding "/" automatically to the end of my endpoints whereas google chrome did. So I proceeded to add it manually and it works fine